# how to handle input for objects when the object has not yet been declared in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object

```html
<input type="text" v-model="object[obj]">
```

Output:

```
object:{'obj1':value}
```

Desired result when input is entered:

```
object:{'obj1':{'prop1':value,'prop2':value}}
```

```html
<input type="text" v-model="obj">

<input type="text" v-model="object[obj]['prop1']">
<input type="text" v-model="object[obj]['prop2']">
{{object}}
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      obj: '',
      object: {},
    }
  }
}
```

Can this be achieved with `v-model` or some custom input handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a [`change`-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) handler on the `<input>` that uses [`vm.$set()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) to create the new object key:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="obj" @change="onKeyChange">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onKeyChange() {
      const key = this.obj && this.obj.trim()
      if (key) {
        this.$set(this.object, key, { prop1: '', prop2: '' })
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The other `<input>`s that depends on `object[obj]` should be [conditionally rendered with `v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt) to avoid using `prop1`/`prop2` on undefined objects:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-if="object[obj]">
      <input v-model="object[obj]['prop1']">
      <input v-model="object[obj]['prop2']">
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/gOwJrbG)